# Create new instance of settings

Tags: c#, constructor, settings

I'm about to code a vibration analysis program, kind of as a school project, that will measure vibration and some other things using sensor and then analyze them using some algorithms.

Anyway, I want the user to be able to set the parameters and variables and have therefore created some different set of settings. The this is though, since I will have many sensors of the same type (I don't know how many at this point) I would like to create a new set or instance of those settings when adding a sensor. Besides, there are some types of variables I don't know how many instances of that type (like say different RPM to compare the vibrations to) there will be and would therefore like to be able to add another instance of that variable.

Does anyone know how this should be accomplished? It's probably pretty straight forward, but Google gave me nothing and trying to create a new instance using a constructor didn't work at all.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
    AccelerometerSettings Sensor3 = new AccelerometerSettings();
```

gave me a new instance of the settings for an accelerometer named Sensor3, but

```
    Sensor3.accelerometerResolution = 10;
```

(I have a setting in the accelerometersettings of type double called resolution) gives me nothing. Or actually, it gives me an error for the '=' and says it's an invalid token and that accelerometerResolution is a field but used as a type.

Edit: Here's the code for the Settings class that is auto-generated by Visual Studio:

```
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18052
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Fault_detection_system {


    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "11.0.0.0")]
    internal sealed partial class AccelerometerSettings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

        private static AccelerometerSettings defaultInstance = ((AccelerometerSettings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new AccelerometerSettings())));

        public static AccelerometerSettings Default {
            get {
                return defaultInstance;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Accelerometer-Name")]
        public string accelerometerName {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["accelerometerName"]));
            }
            set {
                this["accelerometerName"] = value;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("20.0")]
        public decimal accelerometerResolution {
            get {
                return ((decimal)(this["accelerometerResolution"]));
            }
            set {
                this["accelerometerResolution"] = value;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("10.0")]
        public decimal accelerometerAccuracyUp {
            get {
                return ((decimal)(this["accelerometerAccuracyUp"]));
            }
            set {
                this["accelerometerAccuracyUp"] = value;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("10.0")]
        public decimal accelerometerAccuracyDown {
            get {
                return ((decimal)(this["accelerometerAccuracyDown"]));
            }
            set {
                this["accelerometerAccuracyDown"] = value;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("10")]
        public decimal faultFrequency {
            get {
                return ((decimal)(this["faultFrequency"]));
            }
            set {
                this["faultFrequency"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now that you have told us what you want, **show us** what you have tried... (post your code).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @user2950764 - Don't post your code in the comments.  Please edit your post and add it there.

Comment: Thank's for the heads up, I'll think about that next time! @Brian: I didn't thought I could Edit the post longer than 5 minutes after posted like on the comments, but I've done it now.

Comment: Post the code for the AccelerometerSettings class.

Comment: @JamesR: Since I use the Visual Studio standard class for settings it's a lot of code that are auto generated in that class. Is there any special code of special interest or should I post all of it?

Comment: @user2950764 I'm most interested in seeing the declaration of accelerometerResolution, but now that you say it's a "lot of code", I'm curious how you created the class.

Comment: My crystal ball guessed at what is wrong, the accelerometerResolution assignment is a *statement*.  It must appear inside of a method.  You put it outside of a method, as though it was a declaration.  Completely unguessable from the question btw, very poor code snippet.

Comment: @JamesR.: I've updated the first post with the Settings class. What I would like now is basically just to know how to set the values of my parameters in my new created instance of the AccelerometerSettings class and how to create more instances of the variables (like if I have multiple RPMs to check against but don't know how many at this point). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That is your [Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.save%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class which you can access at runtime by the static property `Default` which gives you access to the loaded settings from the app.config file which is of type `AccelerometerSettings` and there you can access its properties like so:

```
var resolution = AccelerometerSettings.Default.accelerometerResolution;
```

and if you want to change settings and save it in the user.config

```
 AccelerometerSettings.Default.accelerometerResolution = 42.0;
 AccelerometerSettings.Default.Save();
```